# Where can I see the subscription failure in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, subscription, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

I want to see the subscription error massage after the subscription got fails, Where I can see that ?
2.where can i see all the subscription which are created in all over all workspace ?

solution for this
I am able to see the the subscription at specific workspace level

Answer (score 0):

1. In order to see all your subscriptions in one place please follow the following Microsoft Power BI Blog:
   [https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/managing-power-bi-subscriptions-just-got-easier/#:~:text=See%20all%20your%20subscriptions%20in%20one%20place](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/managing-power-bi-subscriptions-just-got-easier/#:%7E:text=See%20all%20your%20subscriptions%20in%20one%20place)
2. For Troubleshooting subscriptions please follow the following documentation:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-troubleshoot-subscribe

Hope this helps, please let me know if you have other queries.

Comment: Hello, Many thanks.
But if there was a problem or something else that prevented the subscription from being sent out? How can we identify the problem then?
Where is the log files?